# Woocommerce make <div> appear when items added to cart

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

This should be simple but for whatever reason it is not working for me.

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
if (sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents ) !== 0) {
    echo '<p>hello there</p>';
}
?>
```

Basically I want the header to display some custom HTML I have created after an item is added to the cart. This code isn't working correctly though.

Can anyone show me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this; it's from the WC function that displays a link to the cart when there are items in the cart. The differences are the use of `global` and the `> 0` operand:

```
global $woocommerce;
if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents) > 0 ) :
    echo '<p>hello there</p>';
endif;
```